# bit-wise matrix transposition in VHDL using blockram

Tags: vhdl

I've been trying to figure out a nice way of transposing a large amount of data in VHDL using a block ram (or similar).

Using a vector of vectors it's relatively easy, but it gets icky for large amounts of data.

I want to use a dual channel block ram so that I can write to the one block and read out the other. write in 8 bit std_logic_vectors, read out 32 bit std_logic_vectors, where the 32 bits is (for first rotation at least) the MSB for input vectors 0 - 31, then 32 - 63 all the way to 294911, then MSB-1, etc.

The case described above is my ideal scenario. Is this even possible? I can't seem to find a nice way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research, and thought, this is my answer to this problem:

Due to the nature of the block ram addressing, the ideal scenario mentioned in the OP is not possible with the current block ram addressing implementation. In order to perform a bitwise matrix transposition in the manner described, the block ram addressing would need to be able to switch between horizontal and vertical. That is, the ram must be accessible both row-wise and column-wise, and the addressing mode must be switchable in real-time. Since a bit-wise data transposition is not really a particularly "useful" transform, there wouldn't really be a reason for the implementation of such a switching scheme. Especially since the whole point of block ram is to store datain chunks of more than 1 bit, and such a transform would scramble the data.

I have discovered a way of changing my design such that 294911 x 8 bits do not need to be transformed at once, but rather done in stages using a process. This does not rely on block ram to perform the transform.

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, I'm assuming 18kbit Xilinx-style BRAMs. I'm most familiar with the Virtex-4, so I'm referring to UG070 for the following. The answer will map trivially to other Xilinx FPGAs, and probably other vendors' parts as well.

The first thing to note is that Virtex-4 BRAMs can be used in dual-port mode with different geometries for each port. However, with 1-bit-wide ports, these RAMs' parity bits aren't useful. Thus, an 18kbit BRAM is only effectively 16kbits here.

Next, consider the number of BRAMs you need just for storage (irrespective of your design.) 294912x8 bits maps to 144 BRAMs, which is a pretty large resource commitment. There's always a balance between throughput, design complexity, and resource requirements; if you need to squeeze every MBit/sec out of the design, maybe a BRAM-based approach is ideal. If not, you should consider whether your throughput and latency requirements allow you to use off-chip RAM instead of BRAM.

If you *do* plan on using BRAMs, then you should consider an array of 18x8 BRAMs. The 8 columns each store a single input bit. Each BRAM is written via a 1-bit port, and read out with a 32-bit port.

Every 8-bit write is mapped to eight one-bit writes (one write to a BRAM in each column.)

Every 32-bit read is mapped to a *single* 32-bit read from a *single* BRAM.

You should need very little sequencing logic (around a RAMB16 primitive) to get this working. The major complexity is how to map address bits between the 1-bit port and the 32-bit port.

Comment: This is a better solution than the one that I thought up earlier: 8 bit writes and 1 bit reads, but I don't think I have enough ccs for 1 cc per bit. 

After thinking about it more, I've realised that this issue inherent to the hardware since the addressing is only really going to be row-wise or column-wise, not both, due to the way the ram is designed. so I'm pretty sure that my ideal scenario is impossible. it doesn't make sense for a ram manufacturer to design ram addressing to be vertical/horizontal swItchable except to solve this specific problem. back to the drawing board it is then.